# Minimizing db queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table containing about 30k rows of data and there's several table associations. The problem is that there's like 18 columns, and each column requires 1 db query.

Here's an example of what I'm doing

```
if col_num == 0
    tmp_string_text = finding_phase
elsif col_num == 1
    tmp_string_text = ""
elsif col_num == 2
    tmp_string_text = ""
elsif col_num == 3
    tmp_string_text =  finding.vuln_finding.severity
elsif col_num == 4
    tmp_string_text = finding_node_ip
elsif col_num == 5
    tmp_string_text =  finding.node.host_name
elsif col_num == 6
    tmp_string_text =  finding.node.dns_name
elsif col_num == 7
    tmp_string_text = finding.port
elsif col_num == 8
    tmp_string_text =  finding.pentest_finding.name
elsif col_num == 9
    tmp_string_text =  finding.vuln_finding.name
elsif col_num == 10
    tmp_string_text = finding.vuln_finding.description
elsif col_num == 11
    tmp_string_text = finding.vuln_finding.solution
elsif col_num == 12
    tmp_string_text = finding.additional_output
elsif col_num == 13
    tmp_string_text = finding.cve
elsif col_num == 14
    tmp_string_text = finding.node.os
elsif col_num == 15
    tmp_string_text =  finding.node.device_type
elsif col_num == 16
    tmp_string_text =  finding.node.scan_time
end
```

As a result, there's going to be 15 queries to the DB per 1 row. Is there any way that I can make this more efficient? This takes a REALLY long time when I have 30k rows.

Comment: This is a Question for Code Review not SO.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117545/9357)

Comment: You really, really need to learn about the `case` statement in Ruby. `tmp_string_text = case (col_num) ...` is the best plan for this type of code as a `case` statement will return a value that can be used for assignment. This is full of useless duplication.

Comment: Interesting. I used case for something similar before all of the if conditions, but sounds like I was missing something else as well. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `includes` method to get all the columns at once and then iterate through the results from memory.

```
Model.includes(:column1, :column2, column3: [:subcolumn1, :subcolumn2])
```

Comment: If for example "Book" has many pages, and pages has many paragraphs, how does this work? Book.includes(:page_name, [:page_paragraph]) or something? Not familiar with this but thanks for your help. Really interested in how this works.

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried it with more than one nested resource. But you could try: `Book.includes(pages: [paragraphs: [:word]])`

Comment: The parameters for the includes method are the associated model you are trying to query. Internally it translates to a SQL JOIN query. Check [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

Comment: It would help if you explained what your model looked like. If it's this hard to query your database maybe the schema is sub-optimal.

Comment: Damn. Using includes seems to have been a great idea for reducing the number of queries, but it seems like calling associations still takes awhile. Like test = User.include(:addresses), and then looping through that with something like test.each do {|user| puts user.address.street_name}. Works but still takes awhile :(

Comment: That is strange. Through how many loops are you getting? What is your performance expectation? You can also do the iterations concurrently with something like [futuroscope](https://github.com/codegram/futuroscope). Just remember to run it in multithreaded version of ruby like Rubinius or JRuby.

Comment: Gotcha. About 30k rows that have many associations in about 4-5 other tables. I'm guessing 20+ minutes is pretty normal considering there's 18 queries per row. Thanks for your help!

Comment: it should not take that long. You can speed by creating indexes in associations. But if you have to make that many queries per row maybe you should reconsider your schema. Also it sounds like you could get all the rows at once and then iterate from memory, don't forget to include all required columns from other tables through a join. It shouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add indexes for columns you are going to be querying against on a regular basis. As a rule of thumb you usually want to add indexes for:

- foreign keys
- columns that need to be sorted,
- lookup fields
- columns that are used in a GROUP BY